# Iterate through the rows of a multidimensional array - Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

[image]

Hello, in this code snippet I assign the string for all 6 rows in the matrix. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to do this in a for loop that iterates through the rows of the matrix. Thanks.

Comment: Notice that the convention on stackoverflow is to post code text not images of code. Having code as text helps to provide an answer without typing the code seen in the image.

Comment: you should read a tutorial about loops ... and other programming basics.

Comment: @AhmedAEK : OP uses list comprehension. It is already a loop and can also be used to assign new values. Hard to guess why this question ... just a test what will happen here on stackoverflow in case of such question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
row_struct = [ ['  | '] ]*5 + [ [6] ]
```

or

```
row_struct = [ [n] for n in range(7) ] 
result=[['  | '] if i<=5 else val for i, val in enumerate(row_struct)]
```

or

```
for i in range(6):
    row_struct[i][0] = '  | '
```

Comment: Sorry, for the lack of clarification. That was my first post on here. Your last solution was what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer to mark the question as answered.